# Como recorrer celdas de una fila de excel, Uno por uno. Python

Tags: python, excel

Buen día, Tengo un pequeño proyecto y necesito recorrer las celdas de una fila seleccionada, Pero recorrer una celda por un determinado tiempo.

Por ejemplo:

La primera celda por defecto A1,B1,C1 Y D1.

Después de 42 segundos pase a la Segunda celda  A2,B2,C2 Y D2.

Después de 42 segundos pase a la tercera celda A3,B3,C3 Y D3.

Como podría lograr eso? Pienso activar todo eso mediante una Funcion con un boton(tkinter)

Hasta el momento solo se que puedo llamar a las celdas especificas que yo marque.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Codigos\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Hoja1')
sheet = wb.active

a = sheet['A1'].value

a1 = sheet['B1'].value

a2 = sheet['C1'].value

a3 = sheet['D1'].value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un f-string para darle forma a un rango "A1:D1" en un lazo y `sleep` del modulo `time` para hacer un retraso en el código (1 segundo en el ejemplo):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from time import sleep

path = 'C:\\Users\\acalobish\\Desktop\\Codigos\\Proyecto\\filtro.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = path)
sheet_ranges = wb["Hoja1"]

for i in range(1, 10):
    num1, num2, num3, num4 = sheet_ranges[f'A{i}:D{i}'][0]
    print(num1.value, num2.value, num3.value, num4.value)
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que busco.

Comment: Disculpa una duda, Es posible hacer que pasen a la siguiente celda después de un numero determinado de ejecuciones en la función? Por ejemplo, Despues de 24 Click en el boton que usa la Funcion Pasaran a A2:D2

Comment: Tenia en mente, Usar los datos de las primeras celdas que extraiga para luego usarlo en otra Funcion que hara webscraping, Pero no me funciona. La ultima idea que se me ocurre es que cambie de celda despues un numero determinado de click en el boton que usa la Funcion. Si eso no me funciona tendria que pensar en otro metodo en que se recorran las celdas y poder usar el valor de cada celda hasta que cambie hasta la siguiente celda 2

Comment: Tendrías que hacer una un función que acumule el valor de una variable global o una propiedad de una clase cada vez que es llamada y que retorne si esta variable es múltiplo de 24 con la operación módulo `return contador % 24 == 0`. Esta función retornará True o False dependiendo de si se ha invocado un número múltiplo de 24 veces.

Answer (score 0):

Para ésto recomiendo que use la librería Pandas y las funciones de los DataFrames, ya que la analogía de los Dataframes, es una hoja de excel

Comment: Gracias por responder, Me podrias dar un ejemplo porfavor?